# how should an api gateway lambda return a redirect URL for login

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway, aws-api-gateway

My Lambda function returns html pages.
I am able to return a complete html successfully from node js 10.x.
So if I access my lambda with api gateway url
https://2kiz3ttah.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage/login
if not logged in the lambda should return a redirect URL.
How to return a URL which opens in the browser, than rendering an HTML page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you have something like:

```
// ...your code
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
  },
  body: html,
};
```

So it should be easy enough to return 3xx based on your custom logic. If your problem is based on cognito auth then I think that you are out of luck since it api gateway will return a 403 before you can do anything. In this scenario you could try implement a custom lambda authoriser so you can implement custom logic

Answer (score 5):

In your Lambda you would simply need to return the following:

```
{
   'statusCode': 302,
   'headers': {
       'Location': 'https://redirect.example.com/path'
   }
}
```

Where `https://redirect.exaaple.com/path` is the URL your path should be redirected to.

This should work for your Lambda if it is a `LAMBDA_PROXY` integration within API Gateway.

More information is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format).